# Packed array declaration in system verilog

Tags: arrays, system-verilog

I came across the below syntax while declaring the packed array .

```
bit arr [bit[3:0];
```

My understanding is, Depth of this arr is 16 and width is 1 bit.
But When i try printing the values using the below loop, it doesn't print anything :

```
foreach(arr[ii])
    $display("arr[%0d] = %0d",ii,arr[ii]);
```

Also, I can able to write & read to any of the indexes like arr[56] = 1 and able to print the same as well without any errors.

Can someone please explain the logic behind this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unpacked associative array whose elements are a single bit, and the the index(key) type is a packed array of 4-bits.

Associative array elements do not get allocated until you make an assignment to a particular key index. So the `foreach` loop will not iterate until there are allocated elements.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Can you also comment on how would i able to access the index out of range (i.e) more than 15 ?

Comment: You can't access index is out of range. Whatever index value you use gets truncated to four bits. 56 (38 hex) gets truncated to 8.